# VBA need to run For loop multiple times to have desired outcome

Tags: excel, vba

I am confused why this VBA code is behaving this strangely:

I have a sheet with a range of dates in the first row.
Now I want to delete the whole column if the date is a saturday/sunday or a bank holiday:

```
holidays = Array("01.01.2022", "15.04.2022", "18.04.2022", "01.05.2022", "26.05.2022", "06.06.2022", "16.06.2022", "03.10.2022", "25.12.2022", "26.12.2022")
    Dim holiday As Variant

    For Each c In Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlToRight)).Cells
        
        For Each holiday In holidays
            If c.Value = CDate(holiday) Then
                c.EntireColumn.Delete
            End If
        Next holiday
        
        If Weekday(c.Value, 2) > 5 Then
            c.EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
        
    Next c
```

If I run this macro it deletes all Saturdays only, if I run it a second time it deletes all Sundays too.

But why does it not delete all Saturdays and Sundays in the first run?

Comment: When deleting, you want to do it backwards.

Comment: ^^^^ "it" being the looping. try `For i = Range("B1").End(xlToRight) to 1 step -1`

Comment: Think about it for a while: you found a Saturday in column B. Now when you delete column B, all columns get shifted to the left i.e. column C becomes now column B but the Loop doesn't know what happened it just continues with column C which is the former column D. So the new column B (containing the Sunday) never got checked. You can either loop backward with a For...Next loop or use the same For Each...Next loop but combine the found cells into a range and when the loop finishes, delete the range's entire columns in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Delete Dates (`Union`)

- This solution uses a `For Each...Next` loop combined with `Union`. It uses `Application.Match` instead of the 'holiday' loop. I got it to work only after the dates were converted to Longs.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteDates()
    
    Dim Holidays() As Variant: Holidays = VBA.Array( _
        "01.01.2022", "15.04.2022", "18.04.2022", "01.05.2022", "26.05.2022", _
        "06.06.2022", "16.06.2022", "03.10.2022", "25.12.2022", "26.12.2022")
    
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 0 To UBound(Holidays)
        Holidays(n) = CLng(CDate(Holidays(n)))
    Next n
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ws.Range("B1", ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
    
    Dim drg As Range
    Dim Holiday As Variant
    Dim CurrDate As Date
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim DontDelete As Boolean
    
    For Each cell In rg.Cells
        ' Delete if not a date, or if Saturday, Sunday, or a holiday.
        If IsDate(cell.Value) Then
            CurrDate = cell.Value
            If Weekday(CurrDate, vbMonday) < 6 Then
                If IsError(Application.Match( _
                        CLng(CurrDate), Holidays, 0)) Then
                    DontDelete = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
        If DontDelete Then
            DontDelete = False
        Else
            If drg Is Nothing Then
                Set drg = cell
            Else
                Set drg = Union(drg, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
                    
    If drg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
     
    drg.EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint in the first comment and this solution here. I've just started today with VBA and learned a lot from your solution.